# Delete by id - Laravel ORM

Tags: laravel, orm

Quiero hacer un **delete by id** con la **ORM** de **Laravel**, y por lo que he leído no es posible, y debe hacerse de una forma parecida a esta.

```
File::find($code)->delete();
```

o

```
$file = File::find($code);
$file->delete();
```

en ambos casos me lanza un error **Call to a member function delete() on null**

El caso es que me borra el registro de la base de datos.

alguien sabría decirme que estoy haciendo mal o si me he dejado algo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error era que solo se puede usar el **find()** cuando queremos buscar por la **primary_key** en mi caso he tenido que usar:

```
$file = File::where('FILE_code', '=', $fileCode);
$file->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar algo como:

```
$file = File::whereCode($code)->first() ;

$file->delete();
```

Cuéntanos como te va.

Answer (score 0):

Intentaste esto?

```
public function destroy($id){
    File::destroy($id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con este codigo

```
public function eliminar(Request $request,$id){
    $file = File::find($id)->delete();
    return 'Eliminado correctamente';
 }
```